# Problem with Wiley NJD class

Tags: errors, compilation-error

**UPDATE:** the problem disappeared after I reinstalled mikTeX. Please thus consider the question closed.

When trying to compile an empty document with mikTeX/pdfLaTeX and WileyNJD-v2 class, I get a strange error message:

```
 *geometry* driver: auto-detecting
 *geometry* detected driver: pdftex ! Undefined control sequence. 
 <argument> ...n {para/end}\@kernel@after@para@end 
                                                   \mode_if_horizontal:TF {\i... 
l.16 \maketitle
```

Below is the source file. There is nothing in it, so I cannot even guess what to search for.

```
\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\articletype{Article Type}%
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author[1]{DK}
\author[2]{DG}
\address[1]{\orgname{YYY}}
\address[2]{\orgdiv{XXX}}
\corres{*DG. \email{DG@gmail.com}}
\abstract[Summary]{Summary.}
\keywords{KW1, KW2}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is an introduction
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your feedback. !

Answer (score 1):

`\author` requires a first name and a surname. The error message they provide is not very helpful!

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\articletype{Article Type}%
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
    
\title{Title}

\author[1]{D K} % <<<<<<<<<<<<< name and surname

\author[2]{D G} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\address[1]{\orgname{YYY}}

\address[2]{\orgname{XXX}}

\corres{*D G. \email{DG@gmail.com}}


\abstract[Summary]{Summary.}
\keywords{KW1, KW2} 

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
    This is an introduction.
\end{document
```

Comment: Dear @Simon, I tried to compile your tex-file, but got the same problem. Please see the screenshot in my question.

Comment: Well, as always, brute force worked. The problem disappeared after I reinstalled mikTeX...